# CKEditor RichCombo

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Does anybody know how to disable the default CKEditor behavior that changes the RichCombo label on click?  I want the label to remain *untouched* regardless of the user selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the richcombo plugin you can alter it at the setValue function (line 292) deleting all the code after the first line

```
this._.value = value;
```

After you verify that this is what you want you can try to put it in a plugin if you don't like to alter the source files. (I didn't try this)

Comment: Fantastic!  I arrived at a similar solution, but - as you suggested - I placed the code in the plugin.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A less hackish way to do it is to set the value to empty when the user moves away from the current selection.

```
  editor.on('selectionChange', function(evt) {
  if (mydropdown && mydropdown.getValue())
    mydropdown.setValue('');
  }
```

If you need to always show it empty run `setTimeout(function(){editor.selectionChange();}, 0)` in your click function.

Comment: This actually kind of feels like a more hackish way to me, sorry :)